# JavaFX: Get bounds of Stage before maximizing

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, javafx-8

I want to get/remember the bounds of a `Stage` before it gets maximized by the user. I noticed that i can add event handlers to the maximized property of the stage, but it does not help me. The stage is already maximized at this point in time and `getX()` or `getWidth()` already report the location or size after the Stage has been maximized.

```java
myStage.maximizedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    double x = myStage.getX(); // already too late, x has changed
    ...
```

How can i get the bounds of the stage *before* it has already changed in size? Is that even possible with the current API?

PS: The bigger goal is it to remember the Stage location, state, and screen. If the user positions the Stage, maximizes it, exits the application, and restarts it again, then i want the Stage to be positioned like it was before the user exited the application. That means i would need to position the new Stage first at the previous unmaximized location and then maximize it, to restore the previous state. But without knowing the size before maximizing this seams impossible to do.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue. the problem is that the X and Y properties are set before the maximized flag, so when maximizing, the XY will be for the maximized window.

For me the solution was to save the old values of X and Y and restoring them when the window is maximized.

```
private Integer stageWidth;
private Integer stageHeight;
private Integer stageX;
private Integer stageY;
private boolean isMaximized = false;

//this values will hold the x and y before maximized
private Integer oldStageX;
private Integer oldStageY;

public void setupStageListeners(Stage stage) {
    stage.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        if (!isMaximized) {
            stageHeight = newVal.intValue();
        }
    });

    stage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        if (!isMaximized) {
            stageWidth = newVal.intValue();
        }
    });

    stage.xProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        if (!stage.isMaximized()) {
            stageX = newVal.intValue();
            //save old value in case of maximizing
            oldStageX = oldVal.intValue();
        }
    });

    stage.yProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        if (!isMaximized) {
            stageY = newVal.intValue();
            oldStageY = oldVal.intValue();
        }
    });

    stage.maximizedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        isMaximized = newVal;

        //if maximized save the X and Y old values
        if(isMaximized) {
            stageX = oldStageX;
            stageY = oldStageY;
        }
    });
}


public void saveWindowState() {
    properties.setProperty(STAGE_WIDTH, String.valueOf(stageWidth));
    properties.setProperty(STAGE_HEIGHT, String.valueOf(stageHeight));
    properties.setProperty(STAGE_X, String.valueOf(stageX));
    properties.setProperty(STAGE_Y, String.valueOf(stageY));
    properties.setProperty(IS_MAXIMIZED, String.valueOf(isMaximized));

    savePropertiesFile();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answer! I spent couple of hours with this thing, thx.

Comment: Finally, I found that the solution for me, before saving the location of stage at close request I memorize the isMaximized property of the stage into a variable, I set the stage maximize to false, which will trigger all listners for width, height, x and y and I memorize them with the variable into my ini file.

Answer (score 1):

When we press the button to maximize the JavaFX window, at first the stage is maximized, and then its properties for the width and height are updated. So, the dimensions of the stage should be remembered only if it is not maximized.

For example, in our project, we save the stage dimensions in config file, and also faced a similar problem. The solution is as follows:

```
stage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if (!stage.isMaximized()) {
        config.setWidth(newVal.intValue());
    }
});

stage.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if (!stage.isMaximized()) {
        config.setHeight(newVal.intValue());
    }
});

stage.maximizedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    config.setMaximized(newVal));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Alastair isn't that wrong.

The javaFX Stage has a `widthProperty` and a `heightProperty` (inherited from `Window` with getters and Setters.
You can register a `ChangeListener` to both properties and safe their state when the Listener catches an Event.

[ChangeListener Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html)

[height- and widthproperty docs in Window.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#getWidth--%20getter%20for%20widthProperty/getter%20for%20heightproperty)

Comment: Does not help. The x and y properties change before the maximized event and the width and height properties change after. Same on the way back to the normal state. I always get a half complete state of the bounds, but never the complete state before or after maximizing.